# Java--Making 10-integer ordering program recursive

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, arraylist

I have a simple problem - I need to order 10 numbers. I had an idea how to do this recursively: Make an array of the 10 numbers, take the maximum of the ten numbers, take it out of the array, and repeat the same function with the nine numbers left. The problem was that I did not know how to implement that. I wrote the program, and it works, only it has a part that repeats all the time but with new arrays, because you cannot change the size of the array.

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        int[] sortedArray = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int in0 = input.nextInt();
        int in1 = input.nextInt();
        int in2 = input.nextInt();
        int in3 = input.nextInt();
        int in4 = input.nextInt();
        int in5 = input.nextInt();
        int in6 = input.nextInt();
        int in7 = input.nextInt();
        int in8 = input.nextInt();
        int in9 = input.nextInt();

        int[] numArray = new int[]{in0, in1, in2, in3, in4, in5, in6, in7, in8, in9};

        int numArrayLength = numArray.length;
        recursiveSort(numArray);
        for (int i=0;i<numArrayLength;i++) {
            System.out.print(numArray[i]+",");
        }
        sortedArray[0] = numArray[0];
        System.out.println(" ");

        int[] numArray2 = Arrays.copyOfRange(numArray, 1, numArrayLength);
        int numArray2Length = numArray2.length;
        recursiveSort(numArray2);
        for (int j=0;j<numArray2Length;j++) {
            System.out.print(numArray2[j]+",");
        }
        sortedArray[1] = numArray2[0];
        System.out.println(" ");

        int[] numArray3 = Arrays.copyOfRange(numArray2, 1, numArray2Length);
        int numArray3Length = numArray3.length;
        recursiveSort(numArray3);
        for (int k=0;k<numArray3Length;k++) {
            System.out.print(numArray3[k]+",");
        }
        sortedArray[2] = numArray3[0];
        System.out.println(" ");

        int[] numArray4 = Arrays.copyOfRange(numArray3, 1, numArray3Length);
        int numArray4Length = numArray4.length;
        recursiveSort(numArray4);
        for (int k=0;k<numArray4Length;k++) {
            System.out.print(numArray4[k]+",");
        }
        sortedArray[3] = numArray4[0];
        System.out.println(" ");

        int[] numArray5 = Arrays.copyOfRange(numArray4, 1, numArray4Length);
        int numArray5Length = numArray5.length;
        recursiveSort(numArray5);
        for (int k=0;k<numArray5Length;k++) {
            System.out.print(numArray5[k]+",");
        }
        sortedArray[4] = numArray5[0];
        System.out.println(" ");

        int[] numArray6 = Arrays.copyOfRange(numArray5, 1, numArray5Length);
        int numArray6Length = numArray6.length;
        recursiveSort(numArray6);
        for (int k=0;k<numArray6Length;k++) {
            System.out.print(numArray6[k]+",");
        }
        sortedArray[5] = numArray6[0];
        System.out.println(" ");

        int[] numArray7 = Arrays.copyOfRange(numArray6, 1, numArray6Length);
        int numArray7Length = numArray7.length;
        recursiveSort(numArray7);
        for (int k=0;k<numArray7Length;k++) {
            System.out.print(numArray7[k]+",");
        }
        sortedArray[6] = numArray7[0];
        System.out.println(" ");

        int[] numArray8 = Arrays.copyOfRange(numArray7, 1, numArray7Length);
        int numArray8Length = numArray8.length;
        recursiveSort(numArray8);
        for (int k=0;k<numArray8Length;k++) {
            System.out.print(numArray8[k]+",");
        }
        sortedArray[7] = numArray8[0];
        System.out.println(" ");

        int[] numArray9 = Arrays.copyOfRange(numArray8, 1, numArray8Length);
        int numArray9Length = numArray9.length;
        recursiveSort(numArray9);
        for (int k=0;k<numArray9Length;k++) {
            System.out.print(numArray9[k]+",");
        }
        sortedArray[8] = numArray9[0];
        System.out.println(" ");

        int[] numArray10 = Arrays.copyOfRange(numArray9, 1, numArray9Length);
        int numArray10Length = numArray10.length;
        recursiveSort(numArray10);
        for (int k=0;k<numArray10Length;k++) {
            System.out.print(numArray10[k]+",");
        }
        sortedArray[9] = numArray10[0];
        System.out.println(" ");

        sortedArray[2] = numArray3[0];
        for (int dasdasd=0;dasdasd<sortedArray.length;dasdasd++) {
            System.out.print(sortedArray[dasdasd]+",");
        }
    }
    private static int[] recursiveSort(int numArray[]) {
        int numArrayLength = numArray.length;
        int maximum = 0;
        for (int i=0;i<numArrayLength;i++) {
            if (numArray[i] > maximum) {
                maximum = numArray[i];
            }
        }

        int indexOfMaximum = -1;

        for (int j=0;j<numArrayLength;j++) {
            if (numArray[j] == maximum) {
                indexOfMaximum = j;
                break;
            }
        }

        int temporary = numArray[0];
        numArray[0] = numArray[indexOfMaximum];
        numArray[indexOfMaximum] = temporary;
        return numArray;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the

```
int[] numArray(n) = Arrays.copyOfRange(numArray(n-1), 1, numArray(n-1)Length);
int numArray(n)Length = numArray(n).length;
recursiveSort(numArray(n));
for (int k=0;k<numArray(n)Length;k++) {
    System.out.print(numArray(n)[k]+",");
}
sortedArray[(n-1)] = numArray(n)[0];
System.out.println(" ");
```

constantly repeats, so there is probably a recursive solution that will work nicely. Maybe I can do something using ArrayLists because their size can change...

Any help will be appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: Recursive?  Maybe.  Could you extract that into its own method and profit from a new found clarity?  ***Yes, immediately.***

Comment: Yes, using methods is going to help you look at your code in a better light.

Comment: [Methods](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_methods.htm) tutorial to get you on your way.  Also, your sort is essentially a bubble sort, one of the worst performing sorts that exist.  Sorting algorithms explained [here](http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? If it's just a sorted array, use Arrays.sort(). If you are learning programming, it may help if you consider sorting collections of arbitrary (and unknown) lengths. Think 100,000 values, give or take.

Comment: Yes, ubiquibacon is right, bubble sort is not your friend; but one thing more expensive than bubble sort is *recursive* bubble sort (as in, a method calling itself), because that, for large enough arrays, leads to stack overflow.

Comment: @user2712050 yup, a fact you can see if you add a few zeros to the array size in the example in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a recursive routine that uses an explicit start index for the part that remains to be sorted:

```
private static void recursiveSort(int[] array, int start) {
    if (start < array.length - 1) {
        int maximum = array[start];
        int maximumIndex = start;
        for (int i = start + 1; i < array.length; ++i) {
            if (array[i] > maximum) {
                maximum = array[i];
                maximumIndex = i;
            }
        }
        if (maximumIndex != start) {
            int tmp = array[start];
            array[start] = array[maximumIndex];
            array[maximumIndex] = tmp;
        }
        recursiveSort(array, start + 1);
    }
}
```

This actually does recursion (unlike your code, which iterates calling a routine named "recursiveSort" but isn't recursive at all). The whole process would be started by calling:

```
recursiveSort(numArray, 0);
```

When it returns, the array will be sorted in descending order.

As a general heuristic, when you are struggling with how to make a method recursive, you should consider adding arguments to the method to help with the bookkeeping.

Answer (score 1):

Is this homework or you just need to have the numbers ordered? Java has an easy way to do this if you use `ArrayList()` instead of `array[]`. You would just need to call `Collections.sort(yourArrayList);`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest not trying to make your own sorting algorithm.  Many smart people have already done that hard work for you.

The "recursive" sort that you were trying to implement (aka bubble sort which Ted has shown you how to truly make recursive) will work, but it is grossly inefficient.  See a comparison of sorting algorithms [here](http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/).

Below is a demo of the algorithm you were trying to implement compared to a shell sort, one of the fastest sorting algorithms available.  The implementation I used was taken from [here](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/21elementary/Shell.java.html).  Run it and you will see that shell sort is on average 7 to 8 times faster than bubble sort.

```
public class SortingDemo {
    // Methods required for Shell sort
    public static void shellSort(Comparable[] a) {
        int N = a.length;
        int h = 1;
        while (h < N/3) h = 3*h + 1;

        while (h >= 1) {
            for (int i = h; i < N; i++) {
                for (int j = i; j >= h && less(a[j], a[j-h]); j -= h) {
                    exch(a, j, j-h);
                }
            }
            assert isHsorted(a, h); 
            h /= 3;
        }
        assert isSorted(a);
    }

    private static boolean less(Comparable v, Comparable w) {
        return (v.compareTo(w) < 0);
    }

    private static void exch(Object[] a, int i, int j) {
        Object swap = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = swap;
    }

    private static boolean isSorted(Comparable[] a) {
        for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++)
            if (less(a[i], a[i-1])) return false;
        return true;
    }

    private static boolean isHsorted(Comparable[] a, int h) {
        for (int i = h; i < a.length; i++)
            if (less(a[i], a[i-h])) return false;
        return true;
    }

    // Method required for "recursive" sort
    private static void recursiveSort(Integer[] array, int start) {
        if (start < array.length - 1) {
            int maximum = array[start];
            int maximumIndex = start;
            for (int i = start + 1; i < array.length; ++i) {
                if (array[i] > maximum) {
                    maximum = array[i];
                    maximumIndex = i;
                }
            }
            if (maximumIndex != start) {
                int tmp = array[start];
                array[start] = array[maximumIndex];
                array[maximumIndex] = tmp;
            }
            recursiveSort(array, start + 1);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int desiredArraySize = 1000;
        int minSizeOfNumberInArray = 0;
        int maxSizeOfNumberInArray = 100;
        Integer[] array = new Integer[desiredArraySize]; // Used Integer instead of int to utilize Comparable interface
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            int randomInt = (int) Math.random() * (maxSizeOfNumberInArray - minSizeOfNumberInArray);
            array[i] = randomInt;
        }

        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        recursiveSort(array, 0);
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        long recursiveSortTime = endTime - startTime;
        System.out.println(String.format("\"Recursive\" sort completed in %d ns", recursiveSortTime));

        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        shellSort(array);
        endTime = System.nanoTime();
        long shellSortTime = endTime - startTime;
        System.out.println(String.format("Shell sort completed in %d ns", shellSortTime));

        System.out.println(String.format("\"Recursive\" sort took %f times longer", (float)recursiveSortTime / (float)shellSortTime));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When learning programming, both writing your own sorting algorithms and your own recursive algorithms are great exercises for solidifying your understanding of how things work.  It's time well invested, even if someone's already done it better.

You noticed a pattern that repeats, and associated that with recursion.  When evaluating whether recursion is a good fit, I would encourage you to tweak that thought process with the notion of "divide-and-conquer".  If you're solving only one element with each recursion, then your stack will grow very deep, which should be avoided.  If you can split your problem into roughly even chunks and process each chunk recursively, then recursion will be a good fit.  Otherwise, a loop is already an excellent fit for repeating patterns.